# How to do custom a view for MkAnnotation View As like custom cell for table view?

Tags: iphone, view, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkpinannotationview

I making an application in which i have to implement feature like custom cell for table view. In that i have required a custom view which i can add with Mk-annotation View as we add custom cell with table view. 
I want to add transparent View On that view i want to add two text field and six images and a label. I want to add for array of point which drop on map view. How implement with no of points on map view?
So i don't have any idea for that How i do that? How add custom view with Mk Annotation view? And how hide default view when custom view appear?

Comment: You need to rephrase your question, its not clear. At all

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your Class as MKMapViewDelegate and fill this method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

There you can return a custom Class, subclass of MKAnnotation View.

See Here for more info:

http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=81